# Need Layered Navigation to lead to a specific part (ID) of page

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I have implemented layered navigation to my homepage that have a top slider, now when I use filtration,it reloads page showing results but slider on top, so I have to scroll down a bit to get to my filtered content.

**=> What I need is simply to add the section ID to URL like :**

> www.example.com/?cat=140#maincontent

How to do it with Magento 2?

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding section ID ('maincontent' in may case) to the following files:

Swatch renderer:

> vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\frontend\templates\product\layered\renderer.phtml

I added #maincontent to this line :

```
 <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label['link'] ?>#maincontent"
```

add the same line above for this file:

> vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\view\frontend\templates\layer\filter.phtml